# Upgrading project to Android Studio 1.0 (Gradle problems)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Just to start I'm very new to android development/android studio/gradle so forgive me if I'm asking a stupid question.

My team has been working on a project with the beta version of android studio, I've just installed the new version (1.0) and i've imported our project from the github remote repo.

When trying to sync the project with gradle i get the error: `Gradle version 2.1 is required. Current version is 2.2.1.` It recommends that I change the distributionUrl in gradle-2.1 but when I do I get the error that the gradle plugin requires 2.2.1.

**The question is why is my project requiring 2.1 and where can I change this?**

Here is my gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.<teamName>.<projectName>"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

buildscript{
    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you still having this problem? If so, are you sure you aren't specifying a different version of the Android-Gradle plugin somewhere else? If you have two build.gradle files and the top-level one has a lower version of the Gradle plugin, I'm not sure that the version in the file in your question will take effect.

Comment: I too face exactly the same issue. Have you found any solutions yet?

Comment: Doc is here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

in the gradle-wrapper.properties use the following

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

in build.gradle use

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
```

also replace

```
runProguard false
```

with

```
 minifyEnabled true
```

I hope this can help

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue that you were and had made the exact same updates as described in the Google docs.

The error I was making was editing my app module's build.gradle, and not the project's build.gradle in the root of the project folder for the `com.android.tools.build` version.

Here's the updated PROJECT's build.gradle file that I'm using that works.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-  projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 21
    buildToolsVersion = "20.0.0"

    minSdkVersion = 15
    targetSdkVersion = 21
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the gradle distribution used go to this file: **{Project folder}/gradle/wrapper/graddle-wrapper.properties**.

Then change the `distributionUrl` to use 2.1:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip
```

Comment: When i do this I get the error: The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.13.2). The recommended version is 1.0.0 When i click 'fix plugin' it changes the distributerUrl back to the 2.2.1 version

Comment: Does it still show `Gradle version 2.1 is required. Current version is 2.2.1.`?

Comment: After the first error and I click fix yeah it goes back to how it was before, when the first error appears though the main error goes away

Comment: Make sure you use Android Studio 1.0 final (as you mentioned, you already do), the Android Gradle Plugin version is 1.0.0 (as in your posted `build.gradle`. Furthermore, change `runProguard false` to `minifyEnabled false` and try again. You can also update the `buildToolsVersion` to `21.1.1` just to make sure everything is up to date.