# Generating a LibGdx project into android studio version 1.0?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, libgdx

I followed the instructions on here http://www.programmingmoney.com/setup-libgdx-android-studio/ for installing and using LibGdx on Android Studio 1.0(official release). I am on step 4, the actual generation step. When I tried import project, I got this exception

```
Gradle version 2.1 is required. Current version is 2.2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\chris\AndroidStudioProjects\SetUpGame\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.1-all.zip.
```

This was a similar error to what this person got in this thread - [Upgrading project to Android Studio 1.0 (Gradle problems)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400793/upgrading-project-to-android-studio-1-0-gradle-problems).

When i went to view gradle-wrapper.properties with notepad ++, this was what i saw

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip
```

which meant that this didn't have to be changed. (the answer that was given in the other thread)

Does anyone know what the issue is? Is Android studio version 1.0 too new for Libgdx? I m not that familiar with Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look through all your **build.gradle** files and update the version of the Android Gradle plugin that's specified. If you see `buildscript` --> `dependencies` blocks, update them to version 1.0.0 of the Android Gradle plugin like so:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
```

I think there may be a bug where if you have the wrong version of the plugin, it gives you a bogus error about having the wrong version of Gradle, and you get ping-ponging error messages when you change it back and forth because it's not fixing the root cause of the error, which is this different version number.

Comment: Yeah in the build.gradle file of the Libgdx game file, i saw this as the classpath,                                            classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-beta-01'                        Is it safe to change that line to                                         classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0' or is it better to wait until LibGdx comes out with some sort of update?

Comment: yeah it wasn't safe to change that. the new classpath couldnt be found